# Generating a list based on other lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists `A2` and `J`.

I am performing an operation such that whenever `J[0][i]=0`, `A3==[0]`. I present the current and expected output.

```
A2 = [[2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 6], [0, 3, 5], [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6], [1, 3, 6], [0, 2, 3, 7, 8, 10], 
      [1, 3, 4, 8, 9, 11], [5, 8, 10], [5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11], [6, 8, 11], [5, 7, 8], [6, 8, 9]]

J=[[0, 2, 0, 6, 7, 9, 10]]
A3=[]
for i in range(0,len(J[0])): 
    if (J[0][i]==0):
        A3==[0]
    else:
        A33=A2[J[0][i]]
        A3.append(A33)
print("A3 =",A3)
```

The current output is :

```
A3 = [[0, 3, 5], [1, 3, 4, 8, 9, 11], [5, 8, 10], [6, 8, 11], [5, 7, 8]]
```

The expected output is :

```
A3 = [[0], [0, 3, 5], [0], [1, 3, 4, 8, 9, 11], [5, 8, 10], [6, 8, 11], [5, 7, 8]]
```

Comment: Typo? `A3==[0]` does nothing…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A2 = [[2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 6], [0, 3, 5], [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6], [1, 3, 6], [0, 2, 3, 7, 8, 10], 
      [1, 3, 4, 8, 9, 11], [5, 8, 10], [5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11], [6, 8, 11], [5, 7, 8], [6, 8, 9]]

J=[[0, 2, 0, 6, 7, 9, 10]]
A3=[]
for i in range(0,len(J[0])): 
    if (J[0][i]==0):
        A3.append([0])  # change here
    else:
        A33=A2[J[0][i]]
        A3.append(A33)
print("A3 =",A3)

#output
A3 = [[0], [0, 3, 5], [0], [1, 3, 4, 8, 9, 11], [5, 8, 10], [6, 8, 11], [5, 7, 8]]
```

Instead of `A3==[0]` please do `A3.append([0])` as `A3==[0]` is comparing `A3` with `0` and it is doing no change to `A3`

Comment: Please add some explanation on what was wrong and what you changed.

Comment: @deceze please see I have updated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes in your code:

```
A3 = []
for i in J[0]:
     if i == 0:
             A3.extend([[0]])
     else:
             A3.extend([A2[i]])
```

Now the value of A3 is:

```
[[0], [0, 3, 5], [0], [1, 3, 4, 8, 9, 11], [5, 8, 10], [6, 8, 11], [5, 7, 8]]
```

Explaination:

In your previous code A3==0 does not insert [0] to your list instead it returs a bool. Since you want to insert 0 as a single element list you can use `extend`  function which lets you append a list with multiple elements.